# convert an object to a class instance

Tags: javascript, object

I have a javascript app that reads a json file on the server; the function that reads the json file returns an object.

Until now I was using that object (it represents an album of photos) in the app, but now I want to make it an instance of a class, so that I'm going to manipulate it through the class methods.

Surely I'm doing something like:

```
var album = new Album(object);
```

My question is: what is the best way to generate the class properties in the constructor? can I iterate on the object properties with something like:

```
Object.keys(object).forEach(function(key) {
  this[key] = object.key;
}
```

or should I assign manually each object property to the corresponding class property?

Comment: Did you try it and see if it worked?

Comment: i doesn't work!

Comment: So then your next step would be to `console.log(this, object.key)` and see what is going on.  Or look at the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, I'm going to say best is a matter of opinion. What you are doing will work and is clean and simple but it should fail due to `this` and the `function` reference also due to the missing `)`.

The following version should work for you.

```
Object.keys(object).forEach((key) => {
  this[key] = object[key];
})
```

Comment: Maybe `object.key` is to be written `object[key]`?

Comment: @PaoloBenvenuto, that is a good catch. I updated my answer accordingly. However, the main thing is to make sure and NOT use `function` because function brings its own `this` in a foreach loop.